# Why does my recursion program print a negative number?

Tags: java, eclipse, recursion, factorial

My code for whatever reason is printing out a negative number when i run it with certain numbers(17). It is supposed to find the factorial of a number and print it out however clearly that isn't happening.

```
package recursion;

public class recursion_1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
int x = factorial(17);
System.out.println(x);
}
public static int factorial(int N) { 
       if (N == 1) return 1; 
       return N * factorial(N-1); 
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're encountering integer overflow.

factorial(17) is 3.5568743e+14, which is well beyond the bounds of `int`. When an integer operation overflows, it can end up negative. For example:

```
int x = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
x++;
System.out.println(x); // Very large negative number
```

In your case, you'll have overflowed several times - even if the result were positive, it still wouldn't be *right*.

If you need integers in the range of [-2<sup>63</sup>, 2<sup>63</sup>-1] you can use `long` instead of `int`. If you want arbitrarily large integers, use `BigInteger` instead. For example:

```
// Note rename of parameter to follow Java conventions
public static BigInteger factorial(int n) {
    return factorial(BigInteger.valueOf(n));
}

public static BigInteger factorial(BigInteger n) {
    if (n.equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        return BigInteger.ONE;
    }
    return n.multiply(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Factorials grow quickly in value, such that 17! (355687428096000) too large to fit in an `int`, causing overflow and the negative number.

Return a `long` from `factorial`, so that when the multiplication occurs, it won't overflow (yet).  You'll need to declare `x` as a `long` also.  Note that this will only postpone the problem, because sufficiently high values of `N` will overflow a `long` too.  If necessary, use `BigInteger`s.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the maximum value an `int` can have is `2,147,483,647`. `17!` exceeds this number. If an integer is assigned a number bigger than its maximum size, it starts counting up from `-2,147,483,647`.

```
2,147,483,647 + 1 = -12,147,483,647
```

Try a long or `BigDecimal` instead =)